# Download images with Lightbox.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I am using Lightbox 2 on several image galleries. I would like to provide a way for my users to download the images in the gallery while they are viewing them in the Lightbox. A "Download" button would be perfect, and I picture it down near the caption.

I've already checked the application made by another person here: [Lightbox image download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957647/lightbox-image-download) 
But I could not figure out the answer.

I entered my HTML markup on line 81 of the JS code. 
And it seems perfect, but still doesn't work. 
I have two problems:

1 - I use a tag `A`, but I don't know what to put in the `H REF`. I would like to insert a variable that automatically insert in the `H REF`, the path of the image used in the Lightbox.

2 - Whatever I insert, currently, in the A HREF tag, It doesn't work. I imagine there's a `prevent default` that blocks the default behavior of the tag `A`.

As you can imagine I am not a great expert on JavaScript ... on the contrary.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: I've just add:

`<div class="lb-downloadContainer"><a class="lb-download" title="Download Image" target="_blank" href="http://www.google.it"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a></div>`

Right before opening DIV `lb-closeContainer`.

On line 81 of the file Lightbox.js.

Comment: how to provide href here ?